# Unable to focus window

Tags: windows-8, autoit

There is a problem I cant solve on my own.

I've written this script part:

```
If WinExists("Application") then
        WinActivate("Application")
                ...
                ...
Else
        MsMsgBox($MB_OK,"Attention", "openSiebelOrderScreen: Application not found!")
        _endAutoIT() // ends the script at all
EndIf
```

This works well on all Windows 8 computers except one. There is one laptop system, running Windows 8 as well, but I cant persuade this computer to get the application window in front with the given script part.

I have set `Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)`.

Has somebody the same problem, or maybe a solution for it?

Comment: Did you look a at the return codes of WinExsts and so on?

Comment: Well, WinExists throws no error. I tried to get the window status with WinGetState. On the troublesome Laptop the result is number "16", so AutoIT detects that the application window is there, but is minimized. I will try to force to maximise the application window. Hopefully, it will get into focus then.

Comment: Ok,i solved it for now with this, since i found out, that the application Windows is deteced by AutoIt as minimized, but i need to distinguish between WinActivate and WinSetState. This also puzzles me. But for now: 'WinActivate("Application")
  Sleep (500)
  Local $WinHandle = WinWait("Application","",10)
  If BitAND(WinGetState($WinHandle),16) = 16 Then
   WinSetState($WinHandle, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
  EndIf'

Comment: Nice. Show your code, maybe there some room for improvement.

Comment: In the meantime, i have found other Laptops here, where this problem could be solved. But as well there are Laptops where it works without applying this workaround. Beside other hardware, everything is the same. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended to set these when manipulating windows.

```
#RequireAdmin ;Will give your script a permission elevation (sometimes its needed)
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 4) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also
```

Answer (score 0):

Try elevating your script. Run it as administrator with the same code you use on the other computer which it works.
Probably the laptop's user isn't an administrator and when you run the script it doesn't have administrator privileges.

Remember; for a script to be able to interact with an application, it must be on the same or higher level of the app.

```
#RequireAdmin
```

would be just fine in this case.

Comment: Well, since i have no admin rights on neither machine, as well as the users i tried the script with on the other machines, this would be only academic. But this is a new thought for me. Thanks.